# How to create a hyperlink without displaying the URL path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I create a hyperlink without displaying the URL path?

In my view code, I have something similar to this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to user.lname, [:edit, user] %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

This code works, but produces something like:

```
Smith (url path)
```

I just want "Smith"

Comment: You cannot hide the urls, when the a tag is generated, you will be having something like this: `<a href="/users/smith/edit">Smith</a>` when the view loads.

Comment: Do you mean not displaying the hyperlinks on hover? If that's the case then you can check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12912929/3863146).

Comment: No, not on hover.  Hover is fine.  I mean how it is displayed on page.  The text of the link is not just "Smith" it is like "Smith (http://domain.com/project/users/edit/1)".  I don't want that url to appear on the page.  There must be a way of doing this otherwise Rails SUCKS.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add more detail. We're having to guess what you mean.

Comment: Can you please check your view code that there is no print statement present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  It was in my lousy css.  My css was placing the url in the title of the anchor text.  I learned a lot about link_to also.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you have going on, or are going for with that array object as the URL target, but I'm betting this will solve your problems:

```
<%= link_to user.lname, edit_user_path(user) %>
```

Comment: If you're not sure then ask in a comment. It's better to find out the details ahead of time than to shoot in the dark.

Comment: Point taken. I'm pretty sure that's the solution, just never seen that incantation before.

Answer (score 0):

Rails `link_to` is simply a Helper to create an HTML anchor tag.

You can see in the [ActionView Helper Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) that `link_to` takes 3 parameters.

`link_to(body, url, html_options = {})`

This generates something similar to... 
`<a href="http://website.com/Smith">Smith</a>`

If you wish to change your routes, can you give more information like the full URL that's displaying, your routes.rb files, and the `rake routes` results?

Comment: It's preferable that you ask for additional detail in a comment. Answers are not for discussion. If you don't have the detail you need you should ask for it prior to answering, as that detail can change the information you want to give.

Comment: I answered the best I could with the given information. If I had 50 Reputation to comment, I would've.

Comment: You can gain the reputation by going through various means, besides answering. Submit edits and having them accepted is a good way to learn the site and gain points. I spend a lot of time doing housekeeping, not for points, but because the site needs it. "[answer]" is a good read which will lead you to "[ask]" because knowing what makes a good question is important too.